# Is it a bad idea to use port forwarding as a long-term access strategy?

Tags: firewalls

We are deploying multiple copies of the same system (some devices behind a gateway with NAT), and we need to have continued access for some of those devices. Right now our strategy is to have a set of non-standard ports that are configured to route to specific IP addresses behind the NAT. This setup is essentially replicated for every copy of the system.

Are there any security risks associated with that? Are there any better solutions available to do this?

Comment: Using NAT is very risky as it port forward specific port to public and it will be open to hacker to breach into your system..if you want a long-term access you may consider using reverse ssh connection which means your systems connecting back to you and not open specific port to public waiting for incoming connections Sorry if my idea is not helpful..

Comment: It depends on what kind of access you need - if it's going to be a publicly accessible service, such as HTTP or FTP, then that's perfectly fine, as it's intended for people to access (and you'd have relevant password protection if needed).

Comment: On the other hand, it sounds like you want to use NAT to allow deployment of images or something (would be easier if you could go into some more detail), which is not meant to be visible to the public. In this case, you might consider doing a VPN between routers to allow private communication. Consider adding more details so that the best solution can be found.

Comment: @d0lph1n what you have described is commonly referred as PAT. According to what you've said even routing is very risky since it forwards all the traffic to the destination host.

Answer (score 2):

Most people consider NAT 'security though obscurity' and is a bad idea. Nat should be used to preserve limited IP address space not as security, a good port scanner will find your servers. Most people use NAT AND a firewall, now they can be in the same box. As was indicated above if you want to talk to a business partner you want to use VPN.